# Dynamically populate SVG file using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, svg

I have the following SVG example graph:

http://jovansfreelance.com/bikestats/circos/travels.svg

You can see the source code from there, it's all client-side.

The graph works using sample data. Now, what I need to do is populate is dynamically from the database (or from a file on the server which I could generate using PHP).

Placing PHP code directly into the SVG file doesn't work. Using an onLoad AJAX call doesn't work. It won't let me include jQuery at all. So how do I go about this? I know there's a way but I'm completely new to SVG files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real difference between generating SVG from PHP and generating HTML from PHP. You just need to override the default content-type header (`header('Content-Type: application/svg+xml');`).

Of course, you still need a `.php` file extension as your server won't (by default) be set up to parse `.svg` files for PHP code.

Comment: So, what should the headers be? As it is, if I change the format to `.php` I get the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/frufru/public_html/bikestats/circos/travels.php on line 1`

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to tell the server to parse PHP code in this SVG file? Using htaccess or something?

Comment: The code to set the headers is in the answer. You need to either disable short tags in your PHP install or `echo` your XML declaration from PHP. Yes, Google will tell you how to configure Apache to run PHP in files with different file extensions.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. I'll accept your answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: For me `application/svg+xml` content-type doesn't work to generate a SVG from a PHP file. I used `image/svg+xml` instead.